# Truth of sentences

Tags: predicate-logic

Let say I have a signature  $\{ P_1^1 ,P_2 ^2 , F^2 \}$ with the interpretation $$U= \{ 0,1 \}$$
$$R_1= \{ 0 \}$$ $$R_2= \{ (0,1),(1,0) \}$$
$$F={(0,0,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,1)}$$

I have been given a sentence $$\exists x.P_1 (x)$$

Why is this sentence true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the *interpretation* of $P_1$ is $R_1$ and of $P_2$ is $R_2$, we have that in the *domain* $U$ there is an element, $0$, such that it satisfy the *interpretation* of the predicate symbol $P_1$, that is $R_1$, due to the fact that : $0 \in R_1$.

The inductive definition of the *satisfaction* relation : $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi$ (read : the *structure* $\mathcal M$ *satisfy* the formula $\varphi$) gives us :

> let $\varphi$ a formula with a free variable $x$ and let $D$ the domain of the *structure* $\mathcal M$.

We define :

> > if $\varphi$ is $P_1(x)$, then $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi(a)$ iff $a \in P_1^M$, where $P_1^M$ is the interpretation of $P_1$ in $\mathcal M$ [in our case $R_1$]

And :

> > $\mathcal M \vDash ∃x \varphi$ iff there is some $a \in D$ such that : $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi(a)$.

Comment: In the question I forgot to put what F was, I have added it in. How did you get those curly brackets?

Comment: By my understanding, F contains a mapping from (0,1) to 0 so it is true?

Comment: what about    for all x and some y p2(x,y)  how do the quantifiers change things?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @user204450 - also $\forall x \exists y P_2(x,y)$ is *true* in $U$, because $(0,1) \in R_2$ and $(1,0) \in R_2$ and $0,1$ are the only elements of $U$.

Comment: what is the quantification symbols were swapped for x and y? Also what is |=?

Comment: @user204450 - if you mean $\exists x \forall y P_2(x,y)$, this is not *true* in $U$, because neither $(0,0) \in R_2$ nor $(1,1) \in R_2$.

Comment: where did you get (0,0) and (1,1) from?

Comment: @user204450 - I've found them through the definition of $R_2$; they are the couples **not** in $R_2$ and this means that in the interpretation we are discussing $P_2(0,0)$ and $P_2(1,1)$ do not hold. This is enough to show that in the said interpretation the formula $∃x∀yP_2(x,y)$ is not true.

Comment: What is x and y though? (sorry, I am really bad at logic)